# CacheImpl in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I updated my hibernate version from 5.2.10.Final to 5.3.2.Final and so that 
That CacheImpl class was removed. Does hibernate have alternative of this class and how to monitor cache statistics in the last version of hibernate?

```
((CacheImpl) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()
                          .getCache()).getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name of this class was changed from CacheImpl to CacheImplementor

Comment: To be precise, this was moved to `org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor`