# Hibernate 5.4.25 second level cache and extending the SingletonEhcacheRegionFactory class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, ehcache-2

[In Hibernate 5.2.18](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/caching/Caching.html#caching-provider-ehcache-region-factory), it was possible to set the hibernate configuration option `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` to a class value. This allowed me to extend the class `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` and implement required extra code for my clustered application. This implemented class could then be referenced as the config value for the `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` config in the hibernate settings.

Example in spring-config.xml:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">com.example.MySingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```

Implemented class:

```
public class MySingletonEhCacheRegionFactory extends
        SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory {
// Implementation
}
```

I am now trying to upgrade to version 5.4.25, however [in version 5.3.0](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/7f12e2a1617555cc4806ec730665b4f7c5b0d28c#diff-f7fb913f081bee6842a82b9960d05f19742f166e356c2fb4b4e42887cc33d203) the SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory was moved to an internal class and the code was altered.

On top of this, the `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` config now expects the [shortened name](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12829) for the class. This is stated in the [Hibernate 5.4 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-provider-ehcache-region-factory).

Example:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">ehcache-singleton</prop>
```

So my questions are:

Firstly, is it still possible to extend the `SingletonEhcacheRegionFactory` class from the new location [`org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.SingletonEhcacheRegionFactory`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.4.25/hibernate-ehcache/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cache/ehcache/internal/SingletonEhcacheRegionFactory.java) and add my custom implementation as a shortened value to the hibernate configuration?

Or should I be extending the `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` class instead? It used to be recommended to use the other class over this ([see here](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/hibernate.html)) but it says nothing about version 5+.

> For Hibernate 4, use org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory instead of net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory.

Secondly, can we reference our own class in the hibernate config using the shortened name?

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">myEhcache-singleton</prop>
```

Any insight into the above is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should extent the `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.SingletonEhcacheRegionFactory` class, but the new one is slightly different from the `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` so you will need to rewrite your current code.

If you try to extent `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` you will face some problems like [SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory is no longer available when upgrading from Hibernate 5.2 to 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58250074/singletonehcacheregionfactory-is-no-longer-available-when-upgrading-from-hiberna)

About how to reference it, it is implementing `org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider` interface, like:

```
package my.package.MyStrategyRegistrationProviderImpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.SimpleStrategyRegistrationImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistration;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider;
import org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory;

/**
 * Makes the 1 contained region factory implementations available to the Hibernate
 * {@link org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelector} service.
 */
public class MyStrategyRegistrationProviderImpl implements StrategyRegistrationProvider {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Iterable<StrategyRegistration> getStrategyRegistrations() {
        final List<StrategyRegistration> strategyRegistrations = new ArrayList<StrategyRegistration>( 1 );

        strategyRegistrations.add(
                new SimpleStrategyRegistrationImpl(
                        RegionFactory.class,
                        CustomSingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.class,
                        "custom-ehcache-singleton",
                        CustomSingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.class.getName(),
                        CustomSingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.class.getSimpleName(),
                        // legacy impl class name
                        "org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory",
                        "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"
                )
        );

        return strategyRegistrations;
    }
}
```

and creating a file called:
`META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider` with the full class name:

```
#
# Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
#
# License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later
# See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html
#
#
# Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
#
# License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later
# See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html

my.package.MyStrategyRegistrationProviderImpl
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have solved my problem. I was able to use the `"custom-ehcache-singleton"` in my spring-config.xml file. So `<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">custom-ehcache-singleton</prop>`. Part of my implementation required some other changes, notably this change from CacheImpl. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437551/618465.